# Double pandas groupby operation with pairwise comparison between outer/inner loop groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to do a somewhat complicated pandas groupby operation. Here's some functional but slow pandas code.

```py
# Construct a toy dataframe
idx1 = ["bar", "baz", "foo"]
idx2 = list(range(100, 104))
idx3 = list(range(3))
num_data = len(idx1) * len(idx2) * len(idx3)
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((idx1, idx2, idx3), names=["first", "third", "fourth"])
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=num_data, dtype=bool)
input_df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data={"x": x}).reset_index()
input_df["second"] = "positive"
input_df["second"][input_df["third"] != 100] = "negative"
input_df["third"][input_df["third"] == 101] = 100

# Complication: Not all groups when grouped by "fourth" will have the same indices. Most indices will be shared by most
# "fourth" groups, but the intersection is not complete.
mask = np.ones(num_data, dtype=bool)
mask[[17, 18]] = False
input_df = input_df[mask]
input_df = input_df.set_index(["first", "second", "third", "fourth"])
```

`input_df` looks like this:

```
                                 x
first second   third fourth
bar   positive 100   0       False
                     1       False
                     2        True
      negative 100   0        True
                     1       False
                     2        True
               102   0       False
                     1        True
                     2       False
               103   0        True
                     1       False
                     2        True
baz   positive 100   0       False
                     1       False
                     2       False
      negative 100   0       False # Notice some missing rows here
                     1        True
               102   1        True
                     2        True
               103   0        True
                     1        True
                     2       False
foo   positive 100   0       False
                     1       False
                     2        True
      negative 100   0        True
                     1       False
                     2       False
               102   0       False
                     1        True
                     2        True
               103   0        True
                     1        True
                     2        True
```

Dataframe guarantees/properties:

- There will always be exactly one positive "third" group in each "first group".
- There are N (variable) negative "third" groups in each "first group"

What I want to do efficiently:

- For each "first" group:

  - Compare all negative "third" groups to the single positive "third" group (see code for what "compare" means).

```py
dfs = []
# For for each "first" group:
for first, first_df in input_df.groupby("first"):
    # Separate the positive group and negative groups
    positive_mask = first_df.index.get_level_values("second") == "positive"
    first_df = first_df.droplevel(["first"])
    positive_df = first_df[positive_mask]
    negative_dfs = first_df[~positive_mask]

    positive_df = positive_df.droplevel(["second", "third"])

    # Do some computations w.r.t. each negative "third" group and its corresponding positive group.
    for third, negative_df in negative_dfs.groupby("third"):
        negative_df = negative_df.droplevel(["second", "third"])

        # Compare the positive/negative group based on their "fourth" indices alone
        # Note that for indices not in their intersection "False" is assigned.
        true_true = negative_df["x"] & positive_df["x"]
        true_false = negative_df["x"] & ~positive_df["x"]
        false_false = ~negative_df["x"] & ~positive_df["x"]
        false_true = ~negative_df["x"] & positive_df["x"]

        df = pd.DataFrame({
            "true_true": true_true,
            "true_false": true_false,
            "false_false": false_false,
            "false_true": false_true
        }).reset_index()
        df["first"] = first
        df["second"] = "negative"
        df["third"] = third
        dfs.append(df)
# Output: A big dataframe of the computed values of all the negative "third" groups.
output_df = pd.concat(dfs)
output_df = output_df.set_index(["first", "second", "third", "fourth"], verify_integrity=True).sort_index()
```

That means that `output_df` looks like this. Note the rows that are all false where there were missing "fourth" indices in the original dataframe.

```
                             true_true  true_false  false_false  false_true
first second   third fourth
bar   negative 100   0           False        True        False       False
                     1           False       False         True       False
                     2            True       False        False       False
               102   0           False       False         True       False
                     1           False        True        False       False
                     2           False       False        False        True
               103   0           False        True        False       False
                     1           False       False         True       False
                     2            True       False        False       False
baz   negative 100   0           False       False         True       False
                     1           False        True        False       False
                     2           False       False        False       False # All false from missing data
               102   0           False       False        False       False # All false from missing data
                     1           False        True        False       False
                     2           False        True        False       False
               103   0           False        True        False       False
                     1           False        True        False       False
                     2           False       False         True       False
foo   negative 100   0           False        True        False       False
                     1           False       False         True       False
                     2           False       False        False        True
               102   0           False       False         True       False
                     1           False        True        False       False
                     2            True       False        False       False
               103   0           False        True        False       False
                     1           False        True        False       False
                     2            True       False        False       False
```

Doing this in a loop is extraordinarily slow :( Not only the looping itself, but profiling shows a lot of time being spent doing the inner loop comparison operations since the indices have to be aligned.

Is there a more efficient way to perform this computation, maybe with not so much looping?

---

**EDIT**: Added random seed for deterministic example data & updated input/output data.

Comment: kindly add a `np.random.seed(some number)` to your shared data, so that it is reproducible

Comment: @sammywemmy thanks, great suggestion, done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this, not sure if this is more efficient or not:

```
dfi = input_df['x'].unstack(level=['second','fourth'])

dfi.update(dfi.groupby('first').ffill()[['positive']])

dfi = dfi.stack()
neg_nulls = dfi['negative'].isna()
pos_nulls = dfi['positive'].isna()    
dfi = dfi.fillna(False)
    
dfi['true_true'] = dfi["negative"] & dfi["positive"] 
dfi['true_false'] =  dfi["negative"] & ~dfi["positive"]
dfi['false_false'] =  ~dfi["negative"] & ~dfi["positive"]
dfi['false_true'] =  ~dfi["negative"] & dfi["positive"]
dfi[neg_nulls] = False
dfi[pos_nulls] = False
    
df_out = dfi.rename_axis([None], axis=1)\
   .assign(second='negative')\
   .set_index('second', append=True)\
   .reorder_levels([0,3,1,2])\
   .drop(['positive', 'negative'], axis=1)
```

Output with timings (*Update with np.random.seed(0)*):

```
                             true_true  true_false  false_false  false_true
first second   third fourth                                                
bar   negative 100   0           False        True        False       False
                     1           False       False         True       False
                     2            True       False        False       False
               102   0           False       False         True       False
                     1           False        True        False       False
                     2           False       False        False        True
               103   0           False        True        False       False
                     1           False       False         True       False
                     2            True       False        False       False
baz   negative 100   0           False       False         True       False
                     1           False        True        False       False
                     2           False       False        False       False
               102   0           False       False        False       False
                     1           False        True        False       False
                     2           False        True        False       False
               103   0           False        True        False       False
                     1           False        True        False       False
                     2           False       False         True       False
foo   negative 100   0           False        True        False       False
                     1           False       False         True       False
                     2           False       False        False        True
               102   0           False       False         True       False
                     1           False        True        False       False
                     2            True       False        False       False
               103   0           False        True        False       False
                     1           False        True        False       False
                     2            True       False        False       False
```

***Timings***

> 21.8 ms ± 549 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
> 50.2 ms ± 2.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

```
all(df_out==output_df)
True
```

#### Details

- Reshape input dataframe to have postive and negatives side-by-side
  with 'fourth'
- Fill forward the positives for each 'third' and update dataframe
- Reshape, stacking 'fourths' to have a column of positive next to
  negatives
- Apply true-true ... false-false logic
- Set all Falses for missing negatives and missing positives
- Reshape to get desired output dataframe.

(No looping, but considerable reshaping dataframes)

Comment: That's really something ;-)

Comment: @cydonian  Does this solution help you any?   Did it run almost twice as fast with your data?

Comment: @ScottBoston was still working it out. I might have to update the question - in my real data the "fourth" indices only match within each "first" group, so unstacking the dataframe as a first step gives O(N_firsts) columns.

Comment: Will see if I can adapt your answer and post results.

Comment: @cydonian Good luck.  Happy coding.

Comment: @ScottBoston this answer is great for the question I asked, so selected it as correct.

There were some additional input data characteristics that made this answer not work for my particular use case, namely  that each "first" group draws its "third" and "fourth" indices from a different set. 

I tried to figure out a way to adapt your answer but, alas, I am a pandas noob.

I figured it would be cleaner to just re-ask the modified question, which I've done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67676859/double-pandas-groupby-operation-with-pairwise-comparison-between-outer-inner-loo