# Double pandas groupby operation with pairwise comparison between outer/inner loop groups, pt. 2

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Note: this is a follow-up question to [Double pandas groupby operation with pairwise comparison between outer/inner loop groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67645989/double-pandas-groupby-operation-with-pairwise-comparison-between-outer-inner-loo), which was correctly answered but didn't answer my real question because I wasn't clear enough about the input data.

---

I'm trying to do a somewhat complicated pandas groupby operation. Here's some functional but slow pandas code.

```py
# Construct a toy dataframe
np.random.seed(10)
tups = []
num_third = 4
num_fourth = 3
for i, first in enumerate(["bar", "baz", "foo"]):
    # Each "first" group has its own unique set of "third" and "fourth" index possibilities.
    thirds = np.random.choice(range(i * 100, i * 100 + 50), size=num_third, replace=False)
    # It's possible for the positive group's "third" index to be identical to one of the negative groups.
    if np.random.uniform() < 0.1:
        thirds[0] = thirds[1]

    fourths = np.random.choice(range(i * 100 + 1000, i * 100 + 1050), size=num_fourth, replace=False)
    for (i, third) in enumerate(thirds):
        if i == 0:
            second = "positive"
        else:
            second = "negative"
        for fourth in fourths:
            tups.append((first, second, third, fourth))
num_data = len(tups)
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tups, names=["first", "second", "third", "fourth"])
x = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=num_data, dtype=bool)
input_df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data={"x": x}).reset_index()

# Complication: Not all groups when grouped by "fourth" will have the same indices. Most indices will be shared by most
# "fourth" groups, but the intersection is not complete.
mask = np.ones(num_data, dtype=bool)
mask[[17, 18]] = False
input_df = input_df[mask]
input_df = input_df.set_index(["first", "second", "third", "fourth"])
```

`input_df` looks like this:

```
                                 x
first second   third fourth
bar   positive 37    1031     True
                     1016     True
                     1027    False
      negative 23    1031     True
                     1016     True
                     1027     True
               44    1031     True
                     1016     True
                     1027    False
               42    1031    False
                     1016    False
                     1027    False
baz   positive 104   1137    False
                     1124    False
                     1135     True
      negative 127   1137    False # Notice some missing rows here / partial "fourth" intersection in this "first" group
                     1124    False
               110   1124     True
                     1135    False
               107   1137    False
                     1124     True
                     1135    False
foo   positive 238   1227     True
                     1226     True
                     1237     True
      negative 238   1227    False
                     1226     True
                     1237     True
               245   1227     True
                     1226     True
                     1237     True
               223   1227    False
                     1226     True
                     1237     True
```

Dataframe guarantees / properties:

- There will always be exactly one positive "third" group in each "first group".
- There are N (variable) negative "third" groups in each "first group"
- Each first group has its own set of "third" and "fourth" indices.
- Positive "third" groups within a given "first" group may have the same "third" label, though this is not common.

What I want to do efficiently:

- For each "first" group:

  - Compare all negative "third" groups to the single positive "third" group (see code for what "compare" means).

```py
dfs = []
# For for each "first" group:
for first, first_df in input_df.groupby("first"):
    # Separate the positive group and negative groups
    positive_mask = first_df.index.get_level_values("second") == "positive"
    first_df = first_df.droplevel(["first"])
    positive_df = first_df[positive_mask]
    negative_dfs = first_df[~positive_mask]

    positive_df = positive_df.droplevel(["second", "third"])

    # Do some computations w.r.t. each negative "third" group and its corresponding positive group.
    for third, negative_df in negative_dfs.groupby("third"):
        negative_df = negative_df.droplevel(["second", "third"])

        # Compare the positive/negative group based on their "fourth" indices. Note that for indices not in their
        # intersection "False" is assigned.
        true_true = negative_df["x"] & positive_df["x"]
        true_false = negative_df["x"] & ~positive_df["x"]
        false_false = ~negative_df["x"] & ~positive_df["x"]
        false_true = ~negative_df["x"] & positive_df["x"]

        df = pd.DataFrame({
            "true_true": true_true,
            "true_false": true_false,
            "false_false": false_false,
            "false_true": false_true
        }).reset_index()
        df["first"] = first
        df["second"] = "negative"
        df["third"] = third
        dfs.append(df)
# Output: A big dataframe of the computed values of all the negative "third" groups.
output_df = pd.concat(dfs)
output_df = output_df.set_index(["first", "second", "third", "fourth"], verify_integrity=True).sort_index()
```

That means that output_df looks like this. Note the rows that are all false where there were missing "fourth" indices in the original dataframe.

```
                             true_true  true_false  false_false  false_true
first second   third fourth
bar   negative 23    1016         True       False        False       False
                     1027        False        True        False       False
                     1031         True       False        False       False
               42    1016        False       False        False        True
                     1027        False       False         True       False
                     1031        False       False        False        True
               44    1016         True       False        False       False
                     1027        False       False         True       False
                     1031         True       False        False       False
baz   negative 107   1124        False        True        False       False
                     1135        False       False        False        True
                     1137        False       False         True       False
               110   1124        False        True        False       False
                     1135        False       False        False        True
                     1137        False       False        False       False # All false from missing data
               127   1124        False       False         True       False
                     1135        False       False        False       False # All false from missing data
                     1137        False       False         True       False
foo   negative 223   1226         True       False        False       False
                     1227        False       False        False        True
                     1237         True       False        False       False
               238   1226         True       False        False       False
                     1227        False       False        False        True
                     1237         True       False        False       False
               245   1226         True       False        False       False
                     1227         True       False        False       False
                     1237         True       False        False       False
```

Comment: I think we can either overwrite fourth with default range index per group or create a new 'fourth' as the default range group....  However, let me clarify.   So, since Baz fourth's don't match Bar fourths, can we assume that if there are only two it is the first two?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I fully follow the question. I can say for sure that I need to preserve the full multiindex of each row for subsequent analysis. So I'd need to be able to do `df.loc['baz', 'negative', 110, 1135]["true_true"]` after all is said an done. There's no guarantee about the fourth indices except that there will be some overlap between the negative and positive groups, but the set difference in either direction can be nonempty. There might be "fourth" indices in a negative group not present in the positive one.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an answer that falls slightly short but is good enough for me.

This method, inspired by Scott Boston's answer, is very quick and solves all the requirements *except* for adding all `False` rows for entries where the negative "third" group was missing a "fourth" index. Despite this shortcoming, this solution up being good enough for my purposes with my real dataset so I stopped there, but I can imagine solving the full problem by constructing a new `MultiIndex` with the missing "fourth" entries for each "first" x "third" group and reindexing.

```py
# Get positive/negative entries side by side
dfi = input_df['x'].unstack(level=['second'])
# Copy positive entries into a new column according to the {"first" x "fourth"} index of each for comparison with
# negative indices.
dfi["_positive"] = input_df["x"].loc[:, "positive", :, :].droplevel("third").reindex(
    dfi.index.droplevel("third")).values
# Drop the "third" groups where there was no negative entry to begin with.
dfi = dfi[~dfi["negative"].isna()]

# Do the computation.
dfi['true_true'] = dfi["negative"] & dfi["_positive"]
dfi['true_false'] = dfi["negative"] & ~dfi["_positive"]
dfi['false_false'] = ~dfi["negative"] & ~dfi["_positive"]
dfi['false_true'] = ~dfi["negative"] & dfi["_positive"]

# Reformat to match output_df indices for comparison
dfi = dfi.drop(columns=["positive", "negative", "_positive"])
dfi["second"] = "negative"
dfi = dfi.set_index("second", append=True).reorder_levels(["first", "second", "third", "fourth"])
```

Comparison of my original double loop method to this new vectorized method:

```
N: 10
Douple loop 0.089 s
Vectorized 0.006 s

N: 100
Douple loop 1.206 s
Vectorized 0.007 s

N: 1000
Douple loop 12.502 s
Vectorized 0.019 s
```

That's a 660x speedup!

Full code I used to run the comparison:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string
from codetiming import Timer

np.random.seed(10)
# Construct a toy dataframe
RANDS_CHARS = np.array(list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits),
                       dtype=(np.str_, 1))
num_firsts = 1000
firsts = ''.join(np.random.choice(RANDS_CHARS, num_firsts))
print(f"N: {num_firsts}")

tups = []
num_third = 4
num_fourth = 3
for i, first in enumerate(firsts):
    # Each "first" group has its own unique set of "third" and "fourth" index possibilities.
    thirds = np.random.choice(range(i * 100, i * 100 + 50), size=num_third, replace=False)
    # It's possible for the positive group's "third" index to be identical to one of the negative groups.
    if np.random.uniform() < 0.1:
        thirds[0] = thirds[1]

    fourths = np.random.choice(range(i * 100 + 1000, i * 100 + 1050), size=num_fourth, replace=False)
    for (i, third) in enumerate(thirds):
        if i == 0:
            second = "positive"
        else:
            second = "negative"
        for fourth in fourths:
            tups.append((first, second, third, fourth))
num_data = len(tups)
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tups, names=["first", "second", "third", "fourth"])
x = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=num_data, dtype=bool)
input_df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data={"x": x}).reset_index()

# Complication: Not all groups when grouped by "fourth" will have the same indices. Most indices will be shared by most
# "fourth" groups, but the intersection is not complete.
mask = np.ones(num_data, dtype=bool)
mask[[17, 18]] = False
input_df = input_df[mask]
input_df = input_df.set_index(["first", "second", "third", "fourth"])

dfs = []
with Timer(text="Douple loop {:.3f} s"):
    # For for each "first" group:
    for first, first_df in input_df.groupby("first"):
        # Separate the positive group and negative groups
        positive_mask = first_df.index.get_level_values("second") == "positive"
        first_df = first_df.droplevel(["first"])
        positive_df = first_df[positive_mask]
        negative_dfs = first_df[~positive_mask]

        positive_df = positive_df.droplevel(["second", "third"])

        # Do some computations w.r.t. each negative "third" group and its corresponding positive group.
        for third, negative_df in negative_dfs.groupby("third"):
            negative_df = negative_df.droplevel(["second", "third"])

            # Compare the positive/negative group based on their "fourth" indices. Note that for indices not in their
            # intersection "False" is assigned.
            true_true = negative_df["x"] & positive_df["x"]
            true_false = negative_df["x"] & ~positive_df["x"]
            false_false = ~negative_df["x"] & ~positive_df["x"]
            false_true = ~negative_df["x"] & positive_df["x"]

            df = pd.DataFrame({
                "true_true": true_true,
                "true_false": true_false,
                "false_false": false_false,
                "false_true": false_true
            }).reset_index()
            df["first"] = first
            df["second"] = "negative"
            df["third"] = third
            dfs.append(df)
    # Output: A big dataframe of the computed values of all the negative "third" groups.
    output_df = pd.concat(dfs)
    output_df = output_df.set_index(["first", "second", "third", "fourth"], verify_integrity=True).sort_index()

with Timer(text="Vectorized {:.3f} s"):
    # Get positive/negative entries side by side
    dfi = input_df['x'].unstack(level=['second'])
    # Copy positive entries into a new column according to the {"first" x "fourth"} index of each for comparison with
    # negative indices.
    dfi["_positive"] = input_df["x"].loc[:, "positive", :, :].droplevel("third").reindex(
        dfi.index.droplevel("third")).values
    # Drop the "third" groups where there was no negative entry to begin with.
    dfi = dfi[~dfi["negative"].isna()]

    # Do the computation.
    dfi['true_true'] = dfi["negative"] & dfi["_positive"]
    dfi['true_false'] = dfi["negative"] & ~dfi["_positive"]
    dfi['false_false'] = ~dfi["negative"] & ~dfi["_positive"]
    dfi['false_true'] = ~dfi["negative"] & dfi["_positive"]

    # Reformat to match output_df indices for comparison
    dfi = dfi.drop(columns=["positive", "negative", "_positive"])
    dfi["second"] = "negative"
    dfi = dfi.set_index("second", append=True).reorder_levels(["first", "second", "third", "fourth"])

# Filter out the empty rows from the correct, slow method to check correctness of the rows we did calculate.
compare_rows = output_df.any(axis=1)
assert output_df[compare_rows].equals(dfi)
```